# How to set the ASP.Net Web Services' Date format to ISO?

Tags: asp.net, json, web-services, iso

How can I set the default date format of a web service is to be as the ISO date format? I think it should be edited through 'Web.Config'. I want this to be use with JSON also. But I do not know how to do that. Could someone help me to solve this matter?

Thanks & regards.
Chiranthaka

Comment: What type of web service? WCF, ASMX, WebAPI? WebAPI I believe uses ISO format by default.

Comment: It's an ASMX WebService

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use JavaScript to do that.

Ex :

```
$(function() {

        $("#to_date").datepicker({  maxDate: new Date(),dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd'});
        $("#from_date").datepicker({  maxDate: new Date(),dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd'});


        $("div.ui-datepicker").css( { "font-size": "10px" } );

  });
```